# There exists a Schwartz function which satisfies $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(2^{-k}x)=1, x\ne 0$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Prove that there exists $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$(Schwartz space), satisfying $0\le \varphi \le 1$, $\text{supp}(\varphi)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\frac{1}{2}\le |x|\le 2\}$, such that
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(2^{-k}x)=1, x\ne 0.
$$

This question is relevant to partition of unity, I think there are only finite terms in above equality.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**Construction of $\varphi$**

Take $\rho \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $\operatorname{supp}\rho = [0, 1],$ $0 \leq \rho \leq 1$ and $\int \rho(t) \, dt = 1.$

Let $\sigma(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \rho(s) \, ds.$ Then $\sigma \in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ $\sigma(t)=0$ for $t \leq 0$ and $\sigma(t)=1$ for $t \geq 1.$ Furthermore, $\sigma^{(k)}(0) = 0 = \sigma^{(k)}(1)$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$

Define $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ by
$$
\psi(t) = \begin{cases}
0, & t<-1 \\
\sigma(t+1), & -1 \leq t < 0 \\
1-\sigma(t), & 0 \leq t < 1 \\
0, & t \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ $0 \leq \psi \leq 1$, $\operatorname{supp}\psi = [-1, 1]$ and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \psi(t-k) = 1.$

Finally, set $\varphi(x) = \psi(\log_2|x|).$ Then $\varphi$ fulfills the requested conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your help!